# how to make thin client turned on after turning on server

Tags: vnc, ltsp

I have a LTSP server and 20 thin clients

I have already enabled wake on LAN on every thin client and also I can control(boot,turn of) my thin clients with VNC edition " epoptes"

now I want to understand what command does epoptes executes to boot,turn on ...
so then I'll be able to write script and put in my rc.local file so all of my thin clients turn on after turning on server using wake on LAN which as I said I have already enabled in BIOS.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Epoptes sends [Magic Packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet)

> 6 bytes of all 255 (FF FF FF FF FF FF in hexadecimal)

on low level as described in this [`wol.py` code](https://github.com/epoptes/epoptes/blob/master/epoptes/core/wol.py).

You can use any other program with the same functionality - for example [`wakeonlan`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/wakeonlan):

> Sends 'magic packets' to wake-on-LAN enabled ethernet adapters

Follow its [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/wakeonlan.1.html) for usage istruction.

Comment: thank you for your time and answer/I will try and fill you in if your solution worked out